# Running chi-square in R error: all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

Tags: r, chi-squared

I want to run the Chi square test to see if there is a correlation between income level and bmi level. 
I have the following dataframe called question1Chi:
[image]

(The total number of observations is 403,798)

I tried

```
chisq.test(question1Chi)
```

and get the following error:
all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have `NA` values in your data which break this initially. Even if you fix that, it still won't work because you are dealing with `factor` variables, not numbers. I think you need to do `chisq.test(table(df$X_incomg, df$X_bmi5cat))` to compare within a crosstab. Note however that this will just do a comparison of group counts, without considering the ordinal nature of your variables. You might have to look into something like a 'linear-by-linear association test' to capture this relationship. But with 400K+ cases, you're probably going to find significant results regardless.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I am trying to do that using lbl_test function in package 'coin' however it seems like it requires the dataframe as a table. I tried converting the dataframe to a table using 'as.data.table(df)' however when I use class(df) to inspect it the output gives me "data table" AND "data frame". How can I convert it to a datatable without keeping the original data frame class type?